# How do I import an ECC private key into OpenSSL's EC_KEY?

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to replicate EOS's signing procedure, which uses OpenSSL's `ECDSA_sign` method.

EOS uses secp256k1 curve for signing.

One of the arguments to `ECDSA_sign` is EC_KEY. I assume that the EC_KEY structure contains the type of curve and the private key - but how does one create the EC_KEY structure so that it contains the private key?

Just like bitcoin, the crypto key is encoded in WIF, which I've successfully converted into binary (or hex, if need be). I'm at a loss of where to go from here though.

Do I convert to bignum, and have an EC_KEY import that private key? Is there anything else I'm meant to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSL does not support the WIF format. If you can get the decoded raw private key into a BIGNUM structure (call it `priv_key`) then you should be able to do something like this:

```
EC_GROUP *group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
EC_KEY *key = EC_KEY_new();
EC_POINT *pub_key = EC_POINT_new(group);

EC_KEY_set_group(key, group);
EC_KEY_set_private_key(key, priv_key);
EC_POINT_mul(group, pub_key, priv_key, NULL, NULL, NULL);
EC_KEY_set_public_key(key, pub_key);
```

(Note: the above is completely untested, and for clarity I've omitted all error checking code, which you should add).